# How do I know which RIR server to query for an IP address?

Tags: ip, registrar

How do I know which IP ranges are being allocated to the 5 Regional Internet Registries such as ARIN and RIPE, and thus which whois to query.

If I make it static, how often would I have to update the list? Or are all IPv4 ranges gone now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.txt) is for IPv4, and [this](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-unicast-address-assignments/ipv6-unicast-address-assignments.txt) for IPv6.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I should searched there more.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers seems not to be fully correct. IANA lists 62/8 for RIPE NCC but e.g. for 62.68.234.234 whois.ripe.net will respond with:

> IPv4 address block not managed by the RIPE NCC

I guess the reliable approach would be to load the assignment lists and check against those (like suggested [here](http://blog.erben.sk/2014/01/28/generating-country-ip-ranges-lists/)).

- ftp://ftp.arin.net/pub/stats/arin/delegated-arin-extended-latest
- ftp://ftp.ripe.net/ripe/stats/delegated-ripencc-latest
- ftp://ftp.afrinic.net/pub/stats/afrinic/delegated-afrinic-latest
- ftp://ftp.apnic.net/pub/stats/apnic/delegated-apnic-latest
- ftp://ftp.lacnic.net/pub/stats/lacnic/delegated-lacnic-latest